# Fresh install of iOS 6.0.1 apps constantly crash

Tags: iphone, crash

I just finished a fresh install, started installing apps and signing in again. Every time I login to an app it crashes within a few seconds. Going back in stays there, sometimes crashing again.

I'm new to troubleshooting iOS - what's my next step?

Comment: What does "logging into an app" entail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bought a new iPad 4 with iOS 6.0.1 and apps crash randomly. But as you said most crashes are network related. Using search in music app crashed it while i had enabled home sharing but never when using offline music.
 Safari crashed many times using a proxy server but rarely on no proxy connections.
 Also app store crashed once.

So maybe there is an exception thrown by a network library and not handled correctly in iOS 6.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

While I have had no problems with IOS 6.0.1 installs on the iPhone 4 and 4s in my household some generic troubleshooting steps would include:

NOTE: back up your phone with iTunes before doing any of this!

1. Hold down the top button until the phone prompts you to power it down. Do so. once it is off hold down the top button again till it powers back up.

failing that...

1. Hold down the top and home buttons until it just turns off (ignore the prompt to shut down normally). Once off power up and try again.

failing that...

1. I heard a while back that if you have THREE power downs in a row (as in #2 above) the phone does some major housekeeping on the third time booting up. Not sure if that is true but on a couple of occasions doing three in a row on my iPhone 4 fixed an issue. So do #2 above three times in a row and then test for symptoms.

failing that...

1. Attach the phone to your Mac/PC and when iTunes comes up, click on the iPhone in the side panel and then click on the RESTORE button. That will wipe the phone and then restore from your backup.

failing that...

1. Take it to an Apple store and ask a genius.

Comment: Thanks for the basic steps. Sadly I'd participated in them already. I'm to the Apple store spot and will need to schedule something..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't take the crashes anymore, which totaled 30+ in a day, so I did a fresh Restore again. This somehow cleaned up whatever had occurred. Unfortunately I cannot explain more than this being a fluke.

Comment: Still no good answer. I've been running another fresh install of 6.0.1 since without issue. Might have been a fluke. Alas...

Answer (score 0):

This has also happened to me. It even got to the point where I went to Apple and they just gave me a new iPhone 4S. But about a week later my new iPhone started to do the same thing again.

I'm pretty sure that if you "Restore as new" it will temporarily fix the problem, but it will eventually come back. Hopefully they have something that can fix this in the next iOS 6 update.

Answer (score 0):

Mine has done this twice now since upgrading to iOS 6.0.1. Even iPod crashes when playing music. I nailed it down to something to do with the network. If I put the thing into "Airplane" mode, everything that isn't a network app will work just fine until ***I*** decide to exit.

I really do hope that this is fixed soon, too. Because the full restore is so...time consuming. And temporary.